# Pass events through Protovis Panels

Tags: javascript, dom-events, protovis

I have a Protovis graph that responds to pan/zoom events like the sample on the [website](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/transform.html), which covers the `Panel` that holds the graph with an empty one. Unfortunately it captures all `Events` like `mouseover` and `mouseout` which my underlying graph usually responds to.

This is because you have to set the Panel to accept all events. According to the [docs](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/jsdoc/symbols/pv.Mark.html#events) the only valid params for this are 'all', 'painted' and 'none'

> vis.add(pv.Panel)
>         .events("all")

How can I prevent the zoom `Panel` from capturing these events? Or how can I pass them through to the `Panel` below it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is necessarily the answer you want, but as far as I can tell there's no easy way to pass events through to lower elements. However, if your graph is similar to the example, you can simply change the order of the invisible `Panel` and the marks that should receive events, from:

```
vis.add(pv.Dot)
    .event('click', function() { alert("clicked") })
    // ... etc

vis.add(pv.Panel)
    .events("all")
    // ... etc
```

to:

```
vis.add(pv.Panel)
    .events("all")
    // ... etc

vis.add(pv.Dot)
    .event('click', function() { alert("clicked") })
    // ... etc
```

This will change the z-order of the marks, so that the dots receive click events before the panel. It's a little less plug-and-play, as you have to insert the panel at the correct point in your existing graph, but it should work.

You can see a jsFiddle based on the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Ctxrr/

**EDIT:** Per the comment below, this approach can be a problem for zoom events. The better approach, shown in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Ctxrr/1/), is to make the invisible `Panel` the parent of the marks in question - events will automatically bubble up from child to parent, and if the child doesn't set a listener for an event, it won't interfere with the parent. So as long as all foreground marks that need to receive events are children of the pan/zoom Panel, this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately when you reorder the panels like this the marks will interfere with the pan/zoom events. The user is enable to pan/zoom while the cursor is overtop of a mark.  This becomes a real issue when zooming out, a mark slides under the cursor and you jump all the way down a page.

Comment: @smith324 - Please see my update above. If this approach is possible, it's better than my first suggestion.

Comment: It does zoom correctly but now the pan function doesn't work correctly (its over exaggerated).  I don't have the time now, but will try to debug it later.